# « Je vais me le faire » comment changer le complément ?

Tags: expressions, registre-familier

Dans le langage familier on peut rencontrer l'expression suivante :

> Ah, s'il continue à m'énerver, **je vais me le faire**.

Cette formulation est adaptée si l'on parle de cette situation à un tiers, mais comment tourner cette phrase si l'on s'adresse directement à l'individu concerné ?

Est-ce seulement possible ?

Comment: Remarque au passage : éviter « je vais me le/la faire » appliqué à quelqu'un du sexe opposé. Par exemple, venant d'un homme, « je vais me le faire » est compris par défaut comme « je vais me battre avec lui » ou plus généralement « je vais lui faire du tord », alors que « je vais me la faire » a de grandes chances d'être compris comme « je vais coucher avec elle ».

Comment: @Gilles mouais, plus que du fait que la personne concernée soit ou non du sexe opposé, ça dépend surtout du ton employé...

Comment: En bon québécois « ma tə fʀape » (« _mah t'frapper_ ») qui découle de « je vais te frapper » ! *Qui s'applique si on parle directement à la personne*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Techniquement on obtiendrait par transformation grammaticale directe la formule *Ah, je vais me faire toi!* (totalement inutilisable telle quelle, nous sommes d'accord)

Cependant, même s'il est amusant de chercher à améliorer cette mauvaise transformation en l'habillant un peu, je crois plutôt que beaucoup de personnes, dans le feu de l'action, vont **utiliser la formule telle quelle, comme s'adressant à un tiers invisible**. Je doute que le message soit incompréhensible ou ne serait-ce qu'ambigu pour la personne qui vous voit foncer sur elle en vous écriant *Ah c'ui-là je vais m'le faire !*

---

A l'appui de ma proposition, cet exemple en situation, sous la plume si acérée de notre éternel orateur limousin, où le personnage de l'auteur joue précisément de cette ambiguité dans l'usage de la troisième personne, avec une mauvaise foi hilarante :

> [...] *Tandis qu'il se précipitait vers moi, il me sembla opportun de détourner la conversation, qui pourrait s'avérer houleuse, vers les chemins élevés de la pensée culturelle. D'autant qu'il m'est peu souvent donné d'échanger des idées avec les jeunes dont la promiscuité me répugne généralement autant qu'elle agace les trois bergers allemands qui défendent les barbelés électriques de la maison.*
>
> - Dites-moi, mon jeune ami, lancé-je à ce garçon qui secouait à présent frénétiquement la poignée de ma portière,
>   avez-vous lu Pline l'Ancien ?
>
> **- Ah! Je vais me le farcir. Je sens que je vais me le farcir, me répondit-il.**
>
> - Ah bon ? Et Pline le Jeune ?
>
> - Ah! Je vais me le farcir. Je sens que je vais me le farcir.
>
> *On voit bien, à la lumière de cette historiette édifiante, combien la jeunesse de ce pays est assoiffée de culture.*
>   [...]
>
> (Pierre Desproges, 1982)

Comment: Transformation grammaticale directe… Quitte à choisir, je préfère « je t'offre à moi » plutôt que « je m'offre toi » (ou pis… « je me t'offre »). Mais certes, « je te fais à moi » n'est pas plus compréhensible…

Comment: +1 pour l'hommage à Desproges

Answer (score 7):

Cette expression n'est pas transposable à la deuxième personne.

Des alternatives seraient :

> - Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, je vais te faire ta fête.
> - Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, je vais t'exploser.
> - Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, je vais te défoncer.

Et plein plein d'autres expressions beaucoup plus imagées...

Comment: Comme `te péter la gueule`. Charmant, n'est-ce pas ? Ahaha

Comment: Ou, le plus sobre, `ça va mal se passer`.

Comment: ...ou le *moins* sobre `Ca va chier`.

Answer (score 5):

Lorsque l'on s'adresse directement à la personne concernée, la formulation de cette expression ne me parait pas possible.

Cependant, on emploie souvent d'autres expressions similaires telles que :

> - Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, je vais te frapper
> - Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, tu vas mal finir
> - ...

Answer (score 5):

Il n'est pas possible de passer cette expression au tutoiement, parce que elle considère la personne comme une chose : *le faire* concerne une chose, non une personne. On ne tutoie pas une chose.

De considérer implicitement une personne comme une chose vient son coté insultant.

Et d'où le danger de l'utiliser à propos d'une personne du sexe **complémentaire** (je dis pas opposé, humpf), comme le soulignent les commentaires à la question.

Comment: Et pourtant je te connais comme si je t'avais *fait* ...

Comment: Oui mais là c'est pas pareil.

Answer (score 4):

La seule possibilité que je vois serait :

> Ah, si tu continues à m'énerver, je vais m'occuper de toi !